# Does Tomcat's EL Stream API make sense?

Tags: java, tomcat, el, facelets

I'm testing the Expression Language support for lambda expressions which is well defined in the [EL 3 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/el-3_0-fr-eval-spec/EL3.0.FR.pdf?AuthParam=1471942563_ed0b4e0db5bcfbe73731a9c7d8b4e823). I've got the following test case, using Tomcat 8.0.30 and Mojarra JSF 2.2.12:

**test.xhtml**

```xhtml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">

<h:head />
<h:body>
    <p>
        <h:outputText
            value="#{testBean.values.stream().anyMatch(str -> str == 'Test1')}" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <h:outputText
            value="#{testBean.values.stream().anyMatch(str -> str == 'Test1').get()}" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <h:outputText
            value="#{testBean.values.stream().anyMatch(str -> str == 'Test3').get()}" />
    </p>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**TestBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean {

    private final List<String> values = Arrays.asList("Test1", "Test2");

    public List<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

}
```

I've found, that even the lambda expressions are supported by EL, the Tomcat stream API differs in some way with [the Java's one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) (which returns boolean) and it returns [an Optional](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/el/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(javax.el.LambdaExpression)). So the displayed result is this:

```
org.apache.el.stream.Optional@66a02a04

true

false
```

The same happens for `Stream#allMatch` and `Stream#noneMatch`.

Is there any reason for this?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle, from the Java 8 API, [it returns a boolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-). It's not actually a filter, but a way to check if there's any of them matching the given predicate.

Comment: So somewhere a programmer copied the code for `findAny` at `anyMatch`. _Submit a bugreport._ And better use `findAny.isPresent`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EL 3.0 Stream API was finalized before the Java 8 Stream API. While efforts were made to keep them in sync, there are differences. This is one of them.

Comment: Good to know. I suppose there are no plans to sync it with Java Stream, since it would break backwards compatibility? Thanks!